# New line for label

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I have a Label which I want to shrink into the space.
In my case I want to write the text in two lines:

```
2. New Connection 
Credentials
```

I Tested this but the result is not accomplished:

```
    Label lbb = new Label("2. New Connection Credentials");
    lbb.setMaxWidth(10);
    lbb.setTextOverrun(OverrunStyle.CLIP);
```

How I can split the string into two lines if the size exceeds 10 letters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `lbb.setWrap(true)` to activate text wrapping.